# TabBar controller change the page from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to control the page that is viewed  in the main page from another class.
 tired to use global keys but it doesn't accept the controller to be send to another class and i created a method and tried to control it from first class but still it didn't work and it gives me this error

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (16262): The setter 'index=' was called on null.
I/flutter (16262): Receiver: null
I/flutter (16262): Tried calling: index=1

this is my Home class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tabs/first.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tabs/second.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tabs/third.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController controller;
  //var contKey=GlobalKey<TabBarView>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
        title: Text('hello'),
        bottom: TabBar(controller: controller,tabs: <Widget>[
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),)
        ]),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(controller: controller,children: <Widget>[
        First(),
        Second(),

      ]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: ()=>controller.animateTo(controller.index =1)),

    );


  }


  void next(int num){
    debugPrint(num.toString());
      controller.animateTo(controller.index = num);


}
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
  }
}
```

and this is my first class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tabs/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tabs/second.dart';
class First extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstState createState() => _FirstState();
}

class _FirstState extends State<First> {
Home home = Home();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(onPressed: ()=>debugPrint(''), child: Text('first')),
            FlatButton(onPressed: (){
              Home().createState().next(1);
            }, child: Text('click')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my Second class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Second extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondState createState() => _SecondState();
}

class _SecondState extends State<Second> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: FlatButton(onPressed: ()=>debugPrint('presrt'), child: Text('second')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

what i want is after fixing this problem to be able to have a category list and when the user click on a category it automatically shows the second page with the items in that category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Communication between widgets](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e)

this article answered my question.
it is all about Tabs and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This actually worked for me. Found this off another stack overflow question but I actually cannot find it. So if someone does make add it here.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  int initialPage; //this sets the innitial page to open when main class opens. ie if a main class is opened from secondpage and innitialPage is set to 1 then it will show the second page as the tabpages start from 0.

  MainClass({this.child,@required this.initialPage});

  @override
  _MainClassState createState() => _MainClassState();
}



class _MainClassState extends State<MainClass>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2, initialIndex: 0);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _nextPage(widget.initialPage);
    super.dispose();
  }

  //method to set the page. This method is very important.
  void _nextPage(int tab) {
    final int newTab = _tabController.index + tab;
    if (newTab < 0 || newTab >= _tabController.length) return;
    _tabController.animateTo(newTab);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    return Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text('TabBar Example'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        tabs: <Widget>[
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home, Colors.blue)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.android, color: Colors.blue)),
        ],
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          //make sure the length is set to the number of pages. Also the tabs in the tabbar should be equal to no of pages.
          Center(child: Text("First Page")),//these are pages. You can add pages as your choice
          Center(child: Text("Second Page")),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And if you want to call it from another page. Lets say you want to call it off a button, use the following code to the onpressed event of the button

```js
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return MainClass(initialPage: 1,);
```

According to this it will return the second page of the main class which holds the tab controller as the tabs start from 0. Hope this helps you too :-)

Comment: Is the last part missing some brackets:    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return MainClass(initialPage: 1,);}));

Comment: how to go back with same way you used `push`?