# dart/flutter: change tab content dynamically from separate classes

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm completely new to flutter/dart coming from the .net framework, and I'm just lost! Seems like this would be a simple task, and it probably is for those with more experience.

I've created separate classes in separate files for an AppBar, Tabs, Tab content, and the main code file. Maybe this is my issue?

Anyway, I simply want to change the content of a tab when a DropDownMenu value changes on the AppBar.

I've been googling and trying all kinds of things for a day and a half. I just can't figure out how to make this work!

Not sure where to start with sharing what I've tried...

I tried following this: [TabBar controller change the page from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611277/tabbar-controller-change-the-page-from-another-class)

Have also tried to read this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e. But I think it's just too far over my head at the moment. Need something simple to wrap my brain around.

Also poked around the flutter docs...

Thanks,
Bob